# Androd, I want sync multiple animations which each other, such that each animation is behind the other with fixed time gap

Tags: android, animation, synchronization

I have tried using handlers to start each animation at different time.

I have tried using start offset with different values is each animation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Property Animator` (`ObjectAnimator` or `ValueAnimator` + `AnimatorUpdateListener`)? In this case you can sync multiple animations using an [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#choreography)

Comment: I am using animator set via anim file, I have to sync animation on different views, not on a single view. Whatever I do a fixed time gap between the animations aren't maintained.